# Javascript safely use user regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to safely use regexp that the user inputs in order to parse text. I don't want to use a sandbox or anything. Can I just plug-in the regexp into `String.match` or would that cause problems? If not how might this be avoided?

The usecase is that of a writer who has a lot of text. The writer will transform that text with various regexes. Other users will run that author's regexes in order to get the intended output.

Comment: what type of safety!what kind of input would user match with that regex..elaborate your question before it gets closed

Comment: The user, **U**, gives you the regex and then your JavaScript will use that regex on data that is already in **U**'s browser? No sharing and nothing leaves the browser?

Comment: Is the expression going to be run by users other than the one that enters it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should not cause any security errors. Worse case scenario you are using an invalid regEx string. Unless I am misunderstanding the question.

**EDIT** Worse case scenario is locking up your own browser. Thanks Anirudh for bringing this point up.

Comment: the worst case would be [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) and [DOS attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS)!

Comment: @Anirudh - But those worst cases assume the regex entered by the user is sent to the server and either used there or served back to other users, right? The OP hasn't come back to confirm whether they intend to use it only in the current user's current page or if it'll be sent to the server.

Comment: Ok good point... I thought I would give it a try for fun: http://jsfiddle.net/9EFHU/ ... If you want to blow up your own computer you can I still don't think this is a security vulnerability unless you consider screwing over yourself a violation of security.

Comment: Thanks @Anirudh If that's the worst case then it's alright with me.

Comment: If the regexp is evaluated on the server side... this can cause high CPU usage: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/626

Answer (score 2):

#### User Expression -> Same User

If you have the user input in a string, you can pass that directly to the constructor.

#### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h9jQL/)

```
var s = "This is my text";

$('input#expression').keyup(function(){
    var e = new RegExp($(this).val());
    $('#match').text(
        JSON.stringify(s.match(e))
    );
}).trigger("keyup");
```

It's much better than `eval`.  There aren't any security problems that I know of.  If there are any, it's probably a bug in the browser.

#### User Expression -> Other User(s)

As pointed out in the comments, it would be very complicated to differentiate between safe, and computationally intense/infeasible expressions in JavaScript.

If you don't trust the users to play nice, don't let them run expressions on each other's computers.  At the very least, make sure user data is saved, in the case of the page needing to be refreshed, and don't run them without them being explicitly being invoked by the user.

Comment: This question is about security considerations, not about technical feasibilty.

Comment: what about regexes like `/((((.*)*)*)*)*^/`? These can take a lot of time to evaluate. Denial of service counts as  a security conideration.

Comment: @JanDvorak I have to admit that one ran fine for me. Denial of service doesn't really exist in just the client side unless I misunderstand your meaning.

Comment: @JanDvorak Whose service are you denying though? It's JavaScript, it runs on the user's computer...

Comment: @JanDvorak - It is running on their browser as it is Javascript. Will not effect your web site - their browser goes dead. They will notice that and it does not effect anybody else.

Comment: @JanDvorak - So help me - where does the denial of service come in?

Comment: @WesleyMurch how long strings have you been testing with it? OK, if O(n^5) didn't work, let's try exponential: `(.|..)+^`. 20-30 characters should take a while.

Comment: @EdHeal it hogs up the machine that evaluates the regex. As you say, it doesn't really matter if that machine is client's own.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Javascript it is running on **their** machine - so the sandbox is not involved.

They are free to mess up their machine as much as they want! Besides the worst that can happen is that the script breaks on *their* browser.

Comment: the worst case would be [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) and [DOS attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS)!

Comment: Using the same logic, reflected XSS attacks are nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Kolink and what part make sense!

Comment: @Anirudh "the worst that can hapen is that the script breaks on *their* browser". JavaScript doesn't affect the server (barring AJAX)

Comment: Technically, the regex could run on a node.js server or another client's machine. I suggest rewording. Javascript doesn't imply attacker's own machine.

Comment: @Anirudh - People have a free choice to mess up their own machine. All they need to do is kill the browser. The two things you mention is only a problem if multiple people are using the machine (such as a server). A person is free to b****r up they machines in many more efficient ways.

Comment: @JanDvorak - I would have thought that the person would a) tag it as such b) The problem does not just apply to Javascript in the server setting.

Comment: @Ed: Sure the problem exists in a server JavaScript setting. Say you let the user enter in a regular expression and a piece of text and send it to the server, which will try to match it and send back the result. I'd say that means it applies to JavaScript in a server-side setting, although I do think it's likely that they are only considering using it client-side.

Comment: @icktoofay - I thought they mean the client side as they would have tagged it node.js. Anyway I do not think node.js is a good technology. They is just my opinion - you do not use a tin opener to hammer in a nail